# SQL max number of records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, max, database-trigger

So I have the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE Hospital_MedicalRecord(
        recNo CHAR(5),
        patient CHAR(9),
        doctor CHAR(9),
        enteredOn DATE NOT NULL,
        diagnosis VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        treatment VARCHAR(50),
        PRIMARY KEY (recNo, patient),
        FOREIGN KEY (patient) REFERENCES Hospital_Patient(NINumber),
        FOREIGN KEY (doctor) REFERENCES Hospital_Doctor(NINumber)
    );
```

I want to make it so there are never more that 65,535 medical records for a single patient. Am I supposed to make a new statement or should I implement it in the table above. I can post the patient table if needed.

Comment: Sounds like you'd want an [insert trigger](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/). However, I have to ask if something else is amiss with your system's architecture if you want (presumably) older medical records to simply drop off the system.

Comment: If the table has 65,535 for a single patient (btw if the patient is in the same db, shouldn't it be a foreign key) and someone attempts to insert a new record, what do you want to happen then? Prevent it?

Comment: @BobKaufman Seconded on the insert trigger

Comment: Alternatively, you can build the logic into the INSERT itself

Comment: Check this question, you may find what you are looking for :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758422/mysql-insert-only-if-a-condition-is-true/39759441#39759441

Answer (score 2):

You would typically use a `before insert` trigger for this, that raises an error if the number of records for a patient reached the limit and a new insert is attempted:

```
delimiter //

create trigger Trg_Hospital_MedicalRecord
before insert on Hospital_MedicalRecord
for each row
begin
    if (
        select count(*) from Hospital_MedicalRecord where patient = new.patient
    ) = 65535 then
            set msg = concat('Patient ', new.patient, ' cannot have more than 65535 records');
            signal state '45000' set message_text = msg;
    end if;
end
//

delimiter ;
```

I would assume that you should not allow a `patient` to be updated on an existing record. But if this may happen, then you also need a `before update` trigger (with the very same code).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, user_id INT NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO my_table (user_id)
SELECT 1
  FROM (SELECT 1) x
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT user_id FROM my_table GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) >=3) y
    ON y.user_id = 1
 WHERE y.user_id IS NULL
 LIMIT 1;
```

This limits INSERTS to 3 per user_id.